# C++ style and conversion of 0 to size_t(0)

Tags: c++, substr

Is using `size_t(0)` the same as using `0` in the following code?

```
const string foo = "testing";
const size_t pos = foo.find("i");
string name = foo.substr(size_t(0), pos);
```

That is, when I put only `0` is it converted to `size_t(0)`? If so, is one form preferred over the other? My guess is that `size_t(0)` is the best one to use because it makes the conversion explicit. On the other hand, perhaps some programmers consider `size_t(0)` verbose? I'm guessing in practice no one cares either way.

Comment: Can I just say that of the many different syntaxes C++ supports for type casting, `type(arg)` is not the best in terms of suitability, readability, unambiguousness, etc?

Comment: why not? Maybe because `type` could be read as a function call?

Comment: Yes, and as an instantiation of a class, etc. Writing `(type)arg` is much better, because it only means one thing - type casting. Then the casual reader doesn't have to guess. `static_cast<type>(arg)` is better still in terms of specialisation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That is, when I put only 0 is it converted to size_t(0)?

The conversion is implicit since [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) is:

```
basic_string substr( size_type pos = 0,
                     size_type count = npos );
```

Thus your cast is superfluous.

Comment: That is not the reason. The reason it is implicit cannot be that the member function is declared using a default parameter.

Comment: @dalle: it's not the default value that renders the cast superfluous -- it's the fact that the parameter is size_t, so the `0` will be converted to size_t automatically.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yes the reason is that 0 will will be converted to size_t automatically, but it has nothing to do with the declaration of the function.

Comment: @dalle: The function declaration specifies the parameter type.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: The actual function has nothing to do with it, it would be better to describe the implicit conversions as described in 4 [conv] and 4.5 [conv.prom].

Answer (score 1):

You are type casting the 0 to the same argument type, its a very good practice but not necessary cause this will be converted implicitly.

```
string substr ( size_t pos = 0, size_t n = npos ) const;
```

Check out [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

Comment: IMO it's quite poor practice -- you should generally avoid superfluous casts.

Comment: No it's not, but not preferred.